# How to unmarshall JSON object with multiple value types

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, spray-json

Say I have an object:

```
{
  "name": "joe",
  "age": 60
}
```

How to unmarshall it into a `Map[String, String]` type?

Comment: you can either

 1. unmarshal to Map<String, Object>  2. can create a bean having 2 variable of type String and integer respectively.Once that is done you can use Jackson or Gson to parse the json and convert to the bean.

Answer (score 3):

The [`JsObject`](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/v1.3.4/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsValue.scala#L51) class has a `fields` parameter that is a `Map[String, JsValue]`. If you want a `Map[String, String]`, use `mapValues`:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

val json =
  """{
       "name": "joe",
       "age": 60
     }"""

val jsObj = json.parseJson.asJsObject // JsObject
val myMap: Map[String, String] = jsObj.fields.mapValues(_.toString)

println(myMap)
// Map(name -> "joe", age -> 60)
```